# How do I periodically choose values from a bitmask of allowed values in c?

Tags: c, loops, bit-manipulation

I have a bitmask that encodes "allowed" values. Say the allowed values are the integers `2`, `7` and `12`. The correspondent bitmask of this particular combination would be:

```
unsigned bitmask = (1<<2) | (1<<7) | (1<<12); // = 4228 in decimal
```

I want to fill an array with values periodically chosen from these allowed values listed in the bitmask. So the array should be `unsigned array[] = { 2, 7, 12, 2, 7, 12, 2, 7 /*...*/ };`.

Is there a better (shorter, more intuative, more readable) way than the code below?

```
unsigned array[AR_SIZE];
unsigned it, value = 0;
unsigned bitmask = (1<<2) | (1<<7) | (1<<12); // In reality long long with a few more values

for(it=0; it<AR_SIZE; ++it) {
    do {
        value++;
        if( value > sizeof(value)*8 ) value = 0;
    } while( (bitmask&(1<<value)) == 0 && bitmask > 0 );
    array[it] = value;
}
```

Right now I'm too stupid to think of some XOR, modulus magic to do it in less code and without the extra `value` variable and probably unnecessary do-loop.

Comment: Well... you only need to go once around the loop where you figure out {2,7,12} then just repeatedly copy those values into your array. If your array is quite large then it could be faster like that.

Comment: I only fill the array once. I'm not that much concerned with performance. It's just that so much code, an extra loop and an extra variable for so simple a task keeps bugging my sense of aesthetics. Not so important, but I thought, I might learn something here.

Comment: should not flags be mutually exclusive

Comment: Meaning what exactly?

Comment: True, but I'm sorry, I don't see what this has to do with my opening post.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that uses shifts to determine the numbers in the set then a loop with a modulus to repeatedly move the set into the output array. Is this the sort of simplification you were looking for?

```
unsigned array[17],bitmask,buf[sizeof(array[0])*8],i,pos;

bitmask = (1<<2) | (1<<7) | (1<<12);

for(i=pos=0; i<sizeof(array[0])*8; i++)
    if( (bitmask & (1<<i))!=0 ) buf[pos++] = i;

for(i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++)
    array[i]=buf[i % pos];
```

Comment: Well in some ways it's better (performance) in some ways worse (memory). What I'd like to see is a real one-liner that does away with extra variable such as `buf[]` in your case or `value` in mine and even the loop. Thinking a bit more about it, I guess that's the most concise it will get. I thank you very much none the less.